Webapp dashboard not fetching data from firebase database sent by mobile app
I have a mobile app that sends user location (lat, long, timestamp) to the firebase database. I have a dashboard that should display this location in the browser. However the problem is that the data sent by the mobile app is not displaying in the dashboard browser but when I add data manually to the firebase database keeping the data structure same, the manually entered data shows up in the dashboard.
this is my dashboard code

// Function to fetch and display data
        function fetchData() {
            console.log("Fetching data...");
            db.collection("locations").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                    console.log("No documents found in 'locations' collection.");
                    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '<p>No data found</p>';
                    return;
                }
                console.log("Documents found in 'locations' collection: ", querySnapshot.size);
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const userId = doc.id;
                    console.log(`Fetching subcollection 'dailyLocations' for userId: ${userId}`);
                    doc.ref.collection("dailyLocations").get().then((subQuerySnapshot) => {
                        if (subQuerySnapshot.empty) {
               console.log(`No documents found in 'dailyLocations' subcollection for userId: ${userId}`);
               document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += `<p>No location data for user: ${userId}</p>`;
                        } else {
        console.log(`Documents found in 'dailyLocations' for userId: ${userId}: `, subQuerySnapshot.size);
                            subQuerySnapshot.forEach((subDoc) => {
           const data = subDoc.data();
           const date = new Date(data.timestamp);
           const dateString = `${date.toLocaleDateString()} ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`;
         document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += `<p>User: ${userId}, Latitude: ${data.latitude}, Longitude: ${data.longitude}, Timestamp: ${dateString}</p>`;
                            });
                        }
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Error fetching subcollection: ", error);
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += `<p>Error fetching location data for user: ${userId}</p>`;
                    });
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching main collection: ", error);
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '<p>Error fetching data</p>';
            });
        }

        fetchData();

I tried changing security rules in the database to allow read write if true but still no luck
